# How do I hide results on an empty query in Laravel + Vue?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.4, algolia

Running Laravel Scout + Algolia with Vue. Got it all working and the searching is nice and fast. However I want to hide the results on an empty query instead of displaying the whole index.

Algolia provides this solution:

```
var search = instantsearch({
  [...],
  searchFunction: function(helper) {
    var searchResults = $('.search-results');
    if (helper.state.query === '') {
      searchResults.hide();
      return;
    }
    helper.search();
    searchResults.show();
  }
}
```

Here is my search:

```
//search.blade.php
    <ais-index app-id="{{ config('scout.algolia.id') }}"
               api-key="{{ env('ALGOLIA_SEARCH') }}"
               index-name="dev_users">
        <ais-search-box placeholder="Zoek een gebruiker" :autofocus="true"></ais-search-box>
        <ais-results></ais-results>
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: "#search",
    })
</script>
```

And here is my app.js

```
import InstantSearch from 'vue-instantsearch';
Vue.use(InstantSearch);
```

I can't figure out how to implement the code from the Algolia manual. Can you guys point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can hide results with Vue InstantSearch based on the current query:

```
<template>
  <ais-index :search-store="searchStore">
    <ais-input></ais-input>
    <results v-show="searchStore.query.length > 0"></results>
  </ais-index>
</template>

<script>
import { createFromAlgoliaCredentials } from 'vue-instantsearch';

const searchStore = createFromAlgoliaCredentials('<appId>', '<apiKey>');

export default {
  data() {
    searchStore
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Is there a way to configure Vue InstantSearch not to fire a request when query is empty? I think it's kind of wasteful upon every page load to do a search on an empty string.

Comment: You can `stop()` the search store and `start()` it again when your main component is loaded.
The key here is to not call `refresh()` which will do the Algolia call.
Let me know if that helps @HelenChe